# Unix shell script for tsv file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a scenario where i have to create a tab delimited file (.tsv) using some variable value like the one in below structure

```
$header1 $T $header2 $T $header3
$valueX1 $T $valueY1 $T $valueZ1
$valueX2 $T $valueY2 $T $valueZ2
$valueX3 $T $valueY3 $T $valueZ3

# where $T represent a Tab
```

Can some one please give command to create this file structure using Unix shell script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `echo $header1 \t $header2 \t $header3`

Comment: `echo "$var1\t$var2\t$var3" >>/path/to/file` will append a line containing the contents of the three variables separated by tabs to /path/to/file.

Comment: Seems to me the tricky bit is going to be iterating through your variables... do you really have `$valueX1` etc? Where are you getting these values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `printf` to write a tab character, either by assigning it to a variable `T` like in your example:

```
T=$(printf '\t')
header1=Foo header2=Bar

# The string must be double quoted!
echo "$header1$T$header2"
```

or possibly using it with a here document:

```
cat > file.tsv << EOF
$header1 $T $header2 $T $header3
$valueX1 $T $valueY1 $T $valueZ1
$valueX2 $T $valueY2 $T $valueZ2
$valueX3 $T $valueY3 $T $valueZ3
EOF
```

or by using printf directly:

```
printf "%s\t%s\n" "$header1" "$header2"
```

Comment: @EmacsFodder to use it in a here document for example. And no, POSIX `echo` will not do anything with `\t`.

Comment: You're wrong and you're testing wrong. `T="\t"` just happens to work for you because you're on an XSI system and you are using the variable exclusively in echo statements. Neither `sh` nor `bash` `echo` treats `\t` specially on my system.

Comment: @EmacsFodder I don't even know what you're arguing anymore. Assuming echo will expand `"\t"` will not work in bash unless `xpg_echo` is set, and it may or may not work in `sh` (dash but not ash, zsh but not ksh). This is simply not sh or bash compatible. Even if your echo does `"\t"`, it would not help for any code that used `T="\t"` for anything other than echo.